# Clone a local git feature branch

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have a feature branch in VSTS - feature/someproject. I need to work on the same feature/someproject branch. Here's what I am trying in my laptop to clone the feature stream:

```
/c/work> mkdir test
/c/work> cd test
/c/work/test>git checkout -b feature/test feature/someproject
```

But I get the below error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How can I clone the feature stream locally in my laptop for some work?

Answer (score 0):

you need to first clone the repo.

```
git clone repoAddress
```

Once you have the repository cloned you can checkout the feature branch.

Comment: Thanks but when I issue git checkout -b feature/test feature/someproject I get error - fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'feature/test' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'feature/someproject' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: does your remote already have the feature/somebranch ? can you try git checkout feature/someproject ?

Comment: $ git checkout feature/somebranch 
error: pathspec feature/somebranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: can you see your branch if you do git branch -r

Comment: No I do not see the same - how can I clone from VSTS

Comment: @Prakash You have to **clone** the repository first. When you look at the repository in the web, there is a big button that says **Clone**.

Comment: We have a project which refers to multiple repos / sub-modules. The feature/someproject is under one of the sub-module. VSTS has only the repo of the required sub-module. However when I clone the complete repo and try git checkout feature/someproject I get error - git clone .. cd directory.... git checkout feature/someproject error: pathspec 'feature/someproject' did not match any file(s) known to git. git branch -r does not list the branch feature/someproject also. Hence submodule repo is only exists in VSTS and all local repos have seem to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

- If you **only want to clone the `feature/someproject` branch to a local repo**, you can follow below commands:

  ```
  git clone <VSTS git repo URL> --single-branch feature/someproject --branch feature/someproject
  cd feature/someproject
  ```

  Now the local git will only contain `feature/someproject` branch.
- If your work not only contribute for `feature/someproject` branch, but for for other branches, then you'd better **clone the whole git repo and switch to different branches by `git checkout`**. Such as:

  ```
  git clone <VSTS git repo URL> 
  cd reponame 
  git checkout feature/someproject
  ```
- And if you **already cloned the VSTS git repo**, you should execute git commands under the local git repo's directory (where a hidden `.git` folder located).

Comment: Thanks - I exactly need the 2nd option - We have a project which refers to multiple repos / sub-modules. The feature/someproject is under one of the sub-module. VSTS has only the repo of the required sub-module. However when I clone the complete repo and try git checkout feature/someproject I get error - git clone .. cd directory.... git checkout feature/someproject error: pathspec 'feature/someproject' did not match any file(s) known to git. git branch -r does not list the branch feature/someproject also. Hence submodule repo is only there in VSTS and all local repos have seem to be deleted

Comment: When you clone the main repo, you should also clone the submodules (else, submodule repos won't be cloned). So you can use the command `git clone <main repo URL> --recurse-submodules` to clone the main repo with submodules. And then cd to the submodule and then checkout to feature/someproject branch.